# Extension Method usage in .NET Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to use the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute [ComputeManagementClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.computemanagementclient?view=azure-dotnet)  `Usage` property to list all resource usage through Azure.

I'm specifically using `Usage.ListAsync()` to achieve this. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.iusageoperations?view=azure-dotnet#Applies_to) this is an extension method.

I'm calling the extension method after creating an instance of the ComputeManagementClient using the below:

```
    public async Task<IComputeUsage> GetResourceUsage(int customerId)
    {
        var azureClient = _dbContext.CreateAzureComputeClient(customerId);

        var usageReport = await azureClient.Usage.ListAsync();
    }
```

However, this is returning the following error:

`'IUsageOperations' does not contain a definition for Listasync and the best extention method overload ProvidersOptionsExtensions.ListAsync... Requires a receiver of type 'IProvidersOperations'`.

Is this a bug, or am I calling the method incorrectly?

Edit: I am using the correct namespaces in my code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent;
```

However, VS2017 doesn't indicate the namespace usage (Grey, rather then black colour).

Comment: To use an extension method, you need the namespace: `using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute`. In addition to that, they do not have a parameterless `ListAsync` in their docs.

Comment: @CodingYoshi That's what I first though, but I am using this namespace in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `Usage.ListAsync()` method incorrectly - it looks like a string parameter is needed:

> `ListAsync(IUsageOperations, String, CancellationToken)`
>
> Gets, for the
>   specified location, the current compute resource usage information as
>   well as the limits for compute resources under the subscription.

And indeed, in the code, it mentions that you need a location:

[image]

So update your code to be:

```
var usageReport = await azureClient.Usage.ListAsync("[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts','examplestorage')]");
```

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry I was in the process of updating my own answer. It seems the method extension error was a red herring and it did indeed need a location! Entering a location after installing the namespace sorted the problem.